# Saving listbox items into a csv file

Tags: c#

I have a list box which contains student information, it has a studentID and a student mark, when I write to the file I want the studentID and studentMark to be in separate columns (for example the first students ID will be in A1 and their mark will be in B1. and so on until all the students have been written into the file)

I have this code, but this code only adds the studentinformation into the one column, how would I go about making it split the data and putting them in 2 columns

```
if(lstMarks.Items.Count > 0)
            {
                using(TextWriter outputfile = new StreamWriter("StudentRecords.csv"))
                {
                    foreach(string data in lstMarks.Items)
                    {
                        outputfile.WriteLine(data);
                    }
                    MessageBox.Show("Student Information inserted successfully"); 
                }
            }
```

Comment: What does the data look like?

Comment: @Simon it is studentID and mark Example B00123 : 19.  I store the studentID into a list structure and the mark into another list structure and add them into the list by adding both the variables and using a ":" in between to separate them so I would want the : removed when adding to the file if possible

Comment: data in csv should be separated for example by ','

Comment: @vik_78 Would I add some code into the sample code I gave to do that?

Comment: Try `outputfile.WriteLine(string.Join(",", data.Split(':')));`

Comment: @Archer Thanks that worked, would you be able to explain that code?

Comment: No problem - done :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Saving from a list box to a .csv file in c# Win Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13127033/saving-from-a-list-box-to-a-csv-file-in-c-sharp-win-form)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do what you need...

```
outputfile.WriteLine(string.Join(",", data.Split(':')));
```

What this does it firstly split the string `data` where it finds the colon, and this returns an array.  The `string.Join()` then joins that array back together as a string, using a comma as a separator.

You could alternatively use `data.Replace(":", ",")`.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, so when you say it returns an array do you mean when it splits 'data' it turns data into an array before joining it back together?

Comment: Yes, exactly that.

Comment: I just seen you edit your post, if I was to use replace  would it just be this ```outputfile.WriteLine(data.Replace(":", ",")```

Comment: Side note, this doesn't clear the spaces from around the colon which your example data included, so you'd actually have output data like `B00123 , 19` instead of `B00123,19`.

Comment: Yes.  It's the same result.  It's more habit than anything else for me to use the split & join method as string replace in Javascript only replaces the first instance so you *have* to use split & join (or a regular expression).

Comment: @DanRayson Correct.  Without clear example data, as in `var data = "something : something-else"` this is an answer to the exact question.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a string and WriteLine inside your foreach loop

You will have to split your string so you have `studentId` and `studentMark` in an array. Then you can build a string with comma separated. 
Finally use `flush` to clear all buffers

```
using(TextWriter outputfile = new StreamWriter("StudentRecords.csv"))
{
    foreach(string data in lstMarks.Items)
    {
        var dataArray = data.split(':');
        var line = string.Format("{0},{1}", data[0] , data[1]);
        outputfile.WriteLine(line);
        outputfile.Flush();
    }
    MessageBox.Show("Student Information inserted successfully"); 
}
```